# How to change gameobjects in ContinueWith Firebase auth UNITY3D

Tags: c, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Why is my code not working? I want to change the UI state after auth OK or auth Failed.

```
Services.Api.Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_emailField.text, _passwordField.text).ContinueWith(auth =>
    {
        if (auth.IsFaulted || auth.IsCanceled)
        {
            Services.Loading.Hide();
            Services.StateManager.ShowPopUp(Localisation.GetString("warningTitleText"), auth.Exception.Message.ToString());
            Debug.LogFormat("<color=red><b>[WEB]</b></color>" + " AUTHORIZATION FAULTED");
            return;
        }

        Services.Api.User = auth.Result;

        Services.Photon.Connect();
        Services.StateManager.Switch(nextState);

        Debug.LogFormat("<color=red><b>[WEB]</b></color>" + " AUTHORIZATION OK: {0}   ({1})",
            Services.Api.User.DisplayName, Services.Api.User.UserId);
    });
```

Debug.LogFormat is working, but other code not working:

```
            Services.Loading.Hide();
            Services.StateManager.ShowPopUp(Localisation.GetString("warningTitleText"), auth.Exception.Message.ToString());
```

or

```
        Services.Photon.Connect();
        Services.StateManager.Switch(nextState);
```

Comment: I must add this async to method and can await to continue in main thread:


public async void LoginButton_Click(GameObject newState)
    {
        Services.Loading.Show();

        await Services.Api.Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_emailField.text, _passwordField.text).ContinueWith(
            task => { _taskStatus = task; });
...

Answer (score 0):

From the little code you provided my best guess would be that you are trying to change your "UI State" from some random thread created by "Services.Api.Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync". I'm not too familiar with multithreading in Unity, but usually UI may only be changed by the thread which owns it.

Comment: Whereas in my case I can change the user interface based on whether authorization was successful or not?

Comment: i am absolutely certain there is a way to accomplish what you are trying to do, but you will have to do it on your main thread...
From the little code you provided it is hard to say what's going on and you did not provide any exception information or similar...